# Illustrator blend tool creating unwanted lines

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

I am attempting to create a long shadow on my icon by using [this effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-5sDV5bI4Q) in Illustrator. When I use Object > Blend > Make it leaves white spaces between each shape it creates and looks extremely ugly. How can I fix this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are the white 'strokes' visible when you export the illustration at full-size? It looks like they may just be an Illustrator screen rendering issue.

Answer (score 2):

Change your primary blend objects to have a **fill and no stroke** rather than just a stroke.

When you blend objects with just a stroke, you need to increase the number of blend steps so that the gaps between strokes doesn't appear. By simply using a filled shape for the blend you can achieve easier blends.

**Note in your tutorial link filled shapes are used, not merely stroked shapes.**

Comment: I actually don't have any strokes on the shapes.

Comment: Well what you've posted looks exactly what an object with a stroke and no fill would look like. If you aren't using stroked objects, I don't know what to tell you - make certain anti-alias artwork is checked in the preferences maybe?